Community detection (graph clustering) vs. distance matrix clustering
I need to cluster objects.
Each object is described by the set of features, each of which is either '0' or '1'.
'1' means that object has this feature.
'0' means that there is no information that object has this feature (it can have it, but no one tried to figure out).
There are more features than objects. There are more '0' than '1' for each object (like 90% of the features for each object are 0s).
There are two options for clustering:

Compute distance matrix using given sparse and large feature vectors and cluster it.

Build a network, where nodes are objects, edges connect nodes having the same features set to '1' and edge's width is proportional to the ammount of '1' features shared by the connected nodes; and do community detection (graph clustering) on it.


Are there any theoretical considerations, which can help to select between these two options without doing experiments on simulated dataset or something?

Aren't 1 and 2 noncontradictary? Distance (or similarity) matrix is a way to present a graph.

This situation is similar to single cell gene expression analysis, where there are typically tens of thousands of cells, measured on something like 25k features (genes), with 'present' measurements typically at about 1k-2k features for each cell (and zero for the other features/genes in that cell). In that field, it is common to use the network approach with a network clustering algorithm (Leiden clustering is most commonly used).
Your question is one I've wondered about for a long time. I don't have a fully convincing answer, but here are two aspects that I think come into it. My hunch is that it has to do with very high dimensionality of data. If we were to treat objects simply as vectors, then our normal notions of 'space' may not be useful.
First, given $X$ and $Y$, they live implicitly in a space where $Z = 0.5X + 0.5Y$ lies halfway. However, $Z$ may not denote anything meaningful in the actual object space. Hence, we are working in a space where the vast majority of it (see below) does not actually have any meaning for our universe of objects.
Related, the set-overlap type similarities (used in network construction for this type of data) model the local structure of the object universe in a way that is more useful or faithful (compared to the vector approach). For example, suppose that $J(X,Y)=0.5$, $J(Y,Z)=0.25$ and $J(X,Z) = 0$ (Where $J$ is the Jaccard index between sets), then this could in the network be modelled as two edges with $Y$ in the middle. In the vector space the distance between $X$ and $Z$ is roughly 'maximal' (if we assume $X$ and $Z$ to have a typical number of features; note that the inner product of $X$ and $Z$ is zero), and in that sense can not be distinguished from other pairs at that maximal distance, whereas such other pairs could be far apart in the network model.
There is a link with the curse of dimensionality and distances in high-dimensional space, especially relating to the vastness of such spaces.
It could very well be the case that there are publications in single-cell analysis that address this issue, but I don't have one ready. A nice thing about the network approach is that there are various algorithms that do not require you to supply the number of clusters, but provide a parameter that tunes the granularity of the output clustering (e.g. $\gamma$ in Leiden).
